# Ignoring "jsp:include is not recognized!" error in Aptana HTML editor

Tags: jsp, struts2, aptana, aptana3

I just installed the Aptana plugin into my Eclipse, and I want to use it to edit some .jsp files.

However, I use  and struts tags pretty regularly in my JSP files, and Aptana complains about not recognizing any of them and marking them as errors!

How can I get it to ignore these tags:

```
<jsp:include>
<s:text>
<s:select>
<s:property>
<tiles:insertDefinition>
```

..etc etc..

Answer (score 0):

Go to Eclipse Preferences : Uncheck JSP Validations, then Aptana will ignore JSP fragments.